# Accessing .classList of an existing div

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

I'm a little mystified by how I can't seem to access the classList of a HTMLDivElement. Here's the relevant js code...

```
    var thisDropTarget = document.getElementById(dropTargetId);
    console.log("document.getElementById(draggedId) = "+document.getElementById(draggedId));
    console.log("document.getElementById(draggedId).classList = "+document.getElementById(draggedId).classList);
    document.getElementById(draggedId).classList.remove("dragged");
```

The first console.log says document.getElementById(draggedId) is a [object HTMLDivElement]. The second console.log says the object's classList is undefined. The next line throws the error, saying it's "Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference".

Elsewhere, in a mousemove handler, I check that the dragged element DOES in fact have a class (it has the 'dragged' class).

Any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: Of course I find a solution JUST AFTER asking. I've been checking my project, emulating IE8 from the developer tools and it works when I test it as 'edge'. I'm guessing IE8 doesn't support .classList - is that right?

Comment: check http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist  It's not supported by IE8 and IE9

Comment: You should post your answer to save someone else having to ask the same question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the writer of the question noticing, the issue was because IE didn't have `classList` support until IE10, and even then, it wasn't completely implemented until the Edge rebranding ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)).

However, should you need classList in GTE IE 8, there's a pretty decent polyfill ([github](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js)) that is even embedded in [the MDN page for classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Alternatively, you could write yourself some helper functions and implement the parts of `classList` you want manually, with a detect that loads a "forward to actual `classList` call" version instead should it be available. That's the route I personally went, since I deal with the US education system at work, and school districts are notorious for having ancient hardware. It's a little less taxing on the user's machine should the full power of `classList` not really be needed (ie, you're only using it to add/remove classes from `className`). A sample of these is provided below; note that you could probably improve the regex a smidge.

```js
$.setCls = function(ele, cls) {
    if (!$.hasCls(ele, cls)) ele.className += " " + cls;
};

$.rmCls = function(ele, cls) {
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + cls + "(\\s|$)", "g"), "$2");
};

$.hasCls = function(ele, cls) {
    return ele.className.match("(^| )" + cls + "( |$)");
};

$.togCls = function(ele, cls) {
    if ($.hasCls(ele, cls)) {
        $.rmCls(ele, cls);
    } else {
        $.addCls(ele, cls);
    }
};
```